# how can i extend my own class from VideoView class? Please give an example

Tags: android

I am creating my own class and extending activity to use VideoView class.

How can i extend my own class from VideoView class. here is my code.

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog mProgressdialog = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.videoview);
        StartVideoPlayer();
    }
    private void StartVideoPlayer(){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
        showProgressDialog();
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri video=Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.1.80/movie4.mp4"); 
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mProgressdialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                mProgressdialog.dismiss();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    private void showProgressDialog()
    {
        /** Progress dialog displayed while loading video*/
        mProgressdialog = ProgressDialog.show(VideoPlayer.this, 
                "", "Streaming...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Now i want to  extend VideoPlayer class from VideoView how can i use that. Please help.

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a class `public class extends VideoView`. But from my experience, VideoView is not meant to be extended, it has its own logic and states and most of it's fields are private, and it is not a good attempt to extend it.

(See [a related question of mine regarding the same VideoView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770903/java-class-containing-only-private-members))